# replacing special characters in a .tsv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame I am trying to replace '[' and ']' for my .tsv file.

```
cols_to_check = ['NUMBERS']
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].str.replace({'[':''}, regex=True)
df.to_csv("output.tsv", sep='\t')
```

I'm not sure. The characters don't replace in output. They remain the same. Here is an example of input: ['1,2']

Output: '1,2'

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [pd.Series.str.replace uses two strings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) (or a compiled regex + callable) rather than a dictionary. Further, if we are simply replacing one character (or string) with another, regex can be set to False.

Try the following code instead:

```
cols_to_check = ['NUMBERS']
df[cols_to_check] = df[cols_to_check].str.replace(pat='[', repl='', regex=False)
df.to_csv("output.tsv", sep='\t')
```